# How do I test if something is an array of a given class with Jasmine?

Tags: typescript, jasmine

I am writing an Angular application. I have a test for my component (losely following [this manual](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-basics#component-class-testing)), where I want to check that my `ngOnInit()` calls the provided (mock) service, and initialises my property `foos` with an array of `Foo` objects.

```js
it('should have foos after Angular calls ngOnInit', () => {
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(component.foos).toBeInstanceOf(Foo);
});
```

The above works for a single object, but not for an array. If I check for `Array` the test passes, but isn't particularly useful.

```js
expect(component.foos).toBeInstanceOf(Array);
```

I tried `Foo[]`, but that gave me an error.

> An element access expression should take an argument.

I realise this test is not useful in general because typescript will complain if it returns something that is he wrong class. But I still want to know as a matter of principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this check in Jasmine out of the box, to my knowledge. However, you can use some additional code to achieve this result.

- You can check the contents yourself with [`Array#every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and see if they match. Then use the [`toBeTrue()` matcher](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.6/matchers.html#toBeTrue).

  ```
  expect(someArray.every(x => x instanceof Foo))
    .toBeTrue("Some items don't match");
  ```
- Loop over the array and use the [`toBeInstanceOf()` matcher](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.6/matchers.html#toBeInstanceOf) against each item. You can also add [`withContext()`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.6/matchers.html#withContext) to give additional information, otherwise you won't know which item failed the matcher:

  ```
  for (const [index, x] of someArray.entries()) {
    expect(x)
      .withContext(`index [${index}]`)
      .toBeInstanceOf(Foo, "hello");
  }
  ```
- Loop over the array and manually call [`fail()`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.6/global.html#fail) with an error message:

  ```
  for (const [index, x] of someArray.entries()) {
    if (!(x instanceof Foo)) 
      fail(`index [${index}] is not Foo`, x);
  }
  ```

```js
class Foo { constructor(num) { this._num = num} }; // some dummy implementation
class Bar { constructor(str) { this._srr = str} }; // some dummy implementation

const arrayOfFoos  = [new Foo(1), new Foo(2), new Foo(3)];
const arrayOfBars  = [new Bar("one"), new Bar("two"), new Bar("three")];
const arrayOfMixed = [new Foo(1), new Bar("two"), new Foo(3)];

describe("All Foos", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.array = arrayOfFoos;
  });
  
  it("every() + toBeTrue()", function() {
    expect(this.array.every(x => x instanceof Foo))
      .toBeTrue("Some items don't match");
  });
  
  it("loop + toBeInstanceOf()", function() {
    for (const [index, x] of this.array.entries()) {
      expect(x)
        .withContext(`index [${index}]`)
        .toBeInstanceOf(Foo);
    }
  });
  
  it("loop + fail()", function() {
    for (const [index, x] of this.array.entries()) {
      if (!(x instanceof Foo)) 
        fail(`index [${index}] is not Foo`, x);
    }
  });
});

describe("All Bars", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.array = arrayOfBars;
  });
  
  it("every() + toBeTrue()", function() {
    expect(this.array.every(x => x instanceof Foo))
      .toBeTrue("Some items don't match");
  });
  
  it("loop + toBeInstanceOf()", function() {
    for (const [index, x] of this.array.entries()) {
      expect(x)
        .withContext(`index [${index}]`)
        .toBeInstanceOf(Foo);
    }
  });
  
  it("loop + fail()", function() {
    for (const [index, x] of this.array.entries()) {
      if (!(x instanceof Foo)) 
        fail(`index [${index}] is not Foo`, x);
    }
  });
});

describe("Mixed", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.array = arrayOfMixed;
  });
  
  it("every() + toBeTrue()", function() {
    expect(this.array.every(x => x instanceof Foo))
      .toBeTrue("Some items don't match");
  });
  
  it("loop + toBeInstanceOf()", function() {
    for (const [index, x] of this.array.entries()) {
      expect(x)
        .withContext(`index [${index}]`)
        .toBeInstanceOf(Foo);
    }
  });
  
  it("loop + fail()", function() {
    for (const [index, x] of this.array.entries()) {
      if (!(x instanceof Foo)) 
        fail(`index [${index}] is not Foo`, x);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.6.0/jasmine.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.6.0/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.6.0/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.6.0/boot.min.js"></script>
```